# Howto bulk update a InnoDB table without deadlocks?

Tags: mysql, sql-update, innodb, deadlock

I have two tables, one having a many-to-many relationship (`fooBarTable` with columns `fooId` and `barId`) and another InnoDB table `fooCounterTable` with columns `fooId` and `counter` counting the occurences of `fooId` in `fooBarTable`.

When deleting all `barId`'s from `fooBarTable`, I need to update the `fooCounterTable` accordingly.

The first thing I tried was this:

```
UPDATE fooCounterTable SET counter = counter - 1
    WHERE fooId IN (SELECT fooId FROM fooBarTable WHERE barId = 42 ORDER BY fooId);
```

But I got this error:

```
MySQL error (1205): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Updating the table when adding `barId`'s is working fine with this SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO `fooCounterTable` (fooId, counter) VALUES (42,1), (100,1), (123,1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = counter + 1;
```

So I thought I'd do the same thing when decreasing the counter, even if it looks stupid to insert 0-Values, which should never happen:

```
INSERT INTO `fooCounterTable` (SELECT fooId, 0 FROM fooBarTable WHERE barId = 42 ORDER BY fooId)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = counter - 1;'
```

This seems to work fine in most cases, but sometimes I get a deadlock:

```
MySQL error (1213): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

So I read about deadlocks and found out about `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and I tried this:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT fooId FROM fooCounterTable 
    WHERE fooId IN (SELECT fooId FROM fooBarTable WHERE barId = 42 ORDER BY fooId) FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE fooCounterTable SET counter = counter - 1
    WHERE fooId IN (SELECT fooId FROM fooBarTable WHERE barId = 42 ORDER BY fooId);
COMMIT;
```

which resulted in:

```
MySQL error (2014): commands out of sync
```

Can anyone tell me how to resolve my problem?

**Update**

The last error (2014) occured, because I did not use and free the SELECT statement's results before executing the UPDATE statement, which is mandatory. I fixed that and I got rid of error 2014, but I still have deadlocks (error 1205) from time to time and I don't understand, why.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what fooID you have just deleted when firing this query?

If so seems like this would work...

```
UPDATE fooCounterTable SET counter = 
  (SELECT count(*) FROM fooBarTable WHERE fooId = 42) 
  WHERE fooID = 42
```

I wonder if you really need that counter table tho.  If your indexes are set up properly there  shouldn't be too much of a speed penalty to a more normalized approach.

Comment: Your query is filtering by `fooId` but I need to find all `fooId`'s for a given `barId`. I need the `fooCounterTable` because the `fooBarTable` has half a billion rows and queries usually ask for up to 1000 `fooId` counters. So I'm precomputing the counters for efficiency reasons.